# @font-face issue in IE (works well in Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I am using the font "aracne" in my website : http://festadocinemafrances.com/14a/

(top menu and some titles)

It's working great in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. Here is my CSS :

```
@font-face {    
font-family: aracne;
    src: url('fonts/ARACNE-CONDENSED_regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/ARACNE-CONDENSED_regular.eot?#iefix') format('eot');     /* IE9 */
        }
```

Do you know what could be the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried with other fonts?

Comment: Yes I did. None of them works.

Comment: Except the ones with more sources declared in @font-face : .eot + .woff + .ttf + .svg.